# linker error in C2HS generated C binding

Tags: c, haskell, ffi, c2hs

I build and run the following minimal example (no external dependencies) with 
`C->Haskell Compiler, version 0.25.2 Snowboundest, 31 Oct 2014
  build platform is "x86_64-darwin" <1, True, True, 1>` ; build command:

```
c2hs Structs.chs
ghci Structs.hs
```

but the linker complains with a

```
During interactive linking, GHCi couldn't find the following symbol: get_foo
```

Q : Why is this and how can I fix it? Thx in advance

A : tl;dr : I wasn't compiling the .c into .o object code, DUH!

Code follows:

*Structs.chs*

```hs
module Main where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C

#include "Structs.h"

{#pointer *foo as Foo#}

{#fun get_foo {`Int'} -> `Foo' return* #}

main :: IO ()
main = do
  foo <- get_foo 3
  a1 <- {#get struct foo->a#} foo
  print a1
```

*Structs.h*

```c
struct foo {
  int a;
};

struct foo *get_foo(int n);
```

*Structs.c*

```c
#include "Structs.h"

struct foo f;

struct foo *get_foo(int n)
{
  f.a = n;
  return &f;
}
```

*Structs.hs*

```hs
-- -- C2HS generated Hs file, edited for clarity
module Main where

import Foreign
import Foreign.C

type Foo = Ptr ()

get_foo :: Int -> IO Foo
get_foo p =
  get_foo'_ (fromIntegral p)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  foo <- get_foo 3
  a1 <- (\ptr -> peekByteOff ptr 0 :: IO CInt) foo
  print a1

foreign import ccall safe "Structs.chs.h get_foo"
  get_foo'_ :: CInt -> IO Foo
```

EDIT : `ghc --make Structs.hs` gives the same linker error:

```sh
$ ghc --make Structs.hs
Linking Structs1a ...
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"_get_foo", referenced from:
    _c2MX_info in Structs.o
    _c2Or_info in Structs.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Does it work when just built with GHC (i.e. not loaded with GHCi, but turned into a proper executable)?

Comment: `ghc --make Structs.hs` gives what I believe is the same error, I've edited the question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `get_foo` C function is defined in `Structs.c`, so you need to make that available to GHC.  This ought to work:

```
gcc -o Structs_c.o -c Structs.c
ghc --make Structs.hs Structs_c.o
```

For GHCi, I think you can then just say `ghci Structs.hs Structs_c.o`.  But you definitely need the C object file!